# Data storage size issue on Android - React native app

Tags: android, react-native

I have a React Native app. I just use asyncstorage for access token and user id. After some months, data storage size is 17.96 GB. The app has some lists where I display images, such as users list.
How can I detect why is increasing the storage?

[image: Storage]

Comment: If the app allows backup you can get the app data using `adb backup <packagename>` then use [Android Backup Extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) to convert the backup to a tar archive you can extract and analyze what is so large.

Comment: When I try to open the tar, it says "Unable to unzip". I'm using a mac. Do you know other solutions?